# How can I show only the "top line" of a bar chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot the means for the levels of a factor and instead of showing the values with a bar chart (with `geom_col`) I only want to show the top of the bars. The code below works but it is not elegant (especially how I hard code the `breaks =`  and refer to the labels with `the_means$group` in the `scale_x_continuous()` call.

Is there a clean way to get `ggplot` to draw line segments for each level of a factor?

```r
blah <- 
  data.frame(
    group = factor(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 5))), 
    value = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)
  )

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
the_means <-
  blah |> 
  summarise(
    group_mean = mean(value),
    .by = group
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    x_start = as.numeric(group) - .3,
    x_end = as.numeric(group) + .3,
  )

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_segment(
    aes(x = x_start, xend = x_end, y = group_mean, yend = group_mean),
    data = the_means
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(1, 2), minor_breaks = NULL, labels = the_means$group
  ) +
  expand_limits(y = 0)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geom_tile()` is an easy option, but potentially less customizable. It takes an x and y value, where categorical values are okay. You can access `geom_tile()` through `ggplot2::stat_summary()` using `geom = "tile"` and `fun = mean` to take the means for each each group. From there, the "tile" shape is centered at the value you specify and takes `width` and `height`.

```
ggplot(blah) +
    stat_summary(
        aes(x = group, y = value),
        fun = mean,
        geom = "tile",
        width = 0.6,
        height = 0.05
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer will require the `ungeviz` package which can be had by running `devtools::install_github("wilkelab/ungeviz")`. You can read more about this package and function [here](https://wilkelab.org/ungeviz/reference/geom_hpline.html)

```
base::library(package = dplyr)
base::library(package = ggplot2)
base::library(package = ungeviz)

blah <- 
base::data.frame(
  group = base::factor(c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 5))), 
  value = c(1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12)
  )

ggplot2::ggplot(
  data    = blah,
  mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = group, y = value)
) +
ungeviz::geom_hpline(stat = "summary") # This will give you mean_se()
```

Will get you the following:

[image]

Remember to mark this as solution if it works well for you and feel free to ask additional questions!